# Get previously published messages hazelcasat pubsub

Tags: java, hazelcast

If I publish messages to a certain topic and then later on run a subscriber to that same topic, is there a way to get those previously published messages from the subscriber?

Answer (score 1):

Topic isn't replayable, you can't consume messages published before the consumer subscribes.

A possible workaround is to setup an auxiliary, replayable data buffer to keep historical data. Register a Topic consumer that copies the messages to the buffer.
New Consumers combine the "historical" messages from this buffer with live messages from the Topic, deduplicating them.

[RingBuffer](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/latest/data-structures/ringbuffer.html) can be used as the buffer: it is replayable, keeps the ordering and can be configured to control memory usage (size, TTL), the fault-tolerance model matches the Topic so you can expect similar guarantees.